# Why do I need to lift when using MonadLog with Pipes

Tags: haskell, logging, monad-transformers

I'm trying to get `logging-error` working with `pipes`. I'm nearly there—in the sense that I have something working—but I don't think it's quite right and I don't know how to fix it. The code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

module Main where

import           Protolude hiding ((<>), empty, for, get)

import           Control.Monad.Log
import           Text.PrettyPrint.Leijen.Text

import           Pipes


testApp :: (MonadIO m, MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) m) => m ()
testApp = logInfo $ textStrict "Logging works. Yah!"


printMessage :: (MonadIO m, MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) m) => Consumer Text m ()
printMessage = forever $ await >>= putStrLn


readInputMessage :: (MonadIO m, MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) m) => Producer Text m ()
readInputMessage = forever action      
  where
    action = do
      liftIO $ putStr ("> " :: Text)
      liftIO getLine >>= yield
      lift $ logInfo $ text "Waits with abated breath"


runMyLogging :: MonadIO m => LoggingT (WithSeverity Doc) m a -> m a
runMyLogging f = runLoggingT f (print . renderWithSeverity identity)


runPipesApp :: IO ()
runPipesApp = runMyLogging $ runEffect $
        readInputMessage
    >-> printMessage


runTestApp :: IO ()
runTestApp = runMyLogging testApp


main :: IO ()
main = do
  runTestApp
  runPipesApp
```

In `readInputMessage` I need to `lift` `logInfo` otherwise it won't compile. However `testApp` `logInfo` dosen't need to be lift'ed. Why do I need to lift in one but not the other?

Without `lift` this is the compilation error:

```
/home/rgh/dev/haskell/fa-logging/app/Main.hs:29:7: error:
    • Could not deduce (MonadLog
                          (WithSeverity Doc) (Pipes.Proxy X () () Text m))
        arising from a use of ‘logInfo’
      from the context: (MonadIO m, MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   readInputMessage :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                                       (MonadIO m, MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) m) =>
                                       Producer Text m ()
        at app/Main.hs:23:1-84
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        logInfo $ text "Waits with abated breath"
      In the expression:
        do liftIO $ putStr ("> " :: Text)
           liftIO getLine >>= yield
           logInfo $ text "Waits with abated breath"
      In an equation for ‘action’:
          action
            = do liftIO $ putStr ("> " :: Text)
                 liftIO getLine >>= yield
                 logInfo $ text "Waits with abated breath"
   |
29 |       logInfo $ text "Waits with abated breath"
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

--  While building package fa-logging-0.0.0 using:
      /srv/cache/rgh/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.0.0.2_ghc-8.2.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-2.0.0.2 build lib:fa-logging exe:fa-logging --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I *think* it's not compiling because the compiler can't work out what type `m` is but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the types in `pipes` aren't instances of `MonadLog`.  In `testApp`, you've declared

```
(MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) m) => m ()
```

So we are in an instance of `MonadLog`.  Comparatively, for `readInputMessage`, you've declared

```
(MonadLog (WithSeverity Doc) m) => Producer Text m ()
```

So the type `m` is an instance of `MonadLog`, but we're not *in* type `m ()`.  We're in type `Producer Text m ()`.  Using `lift` then takes us into the `m` monad, which is what you've observed.

The solution is to make the Pipes types members of `MonadLog` when it's inner monad is.  If you're willing to put up with orphan instances, you can write something similar to the code below.

```
instance (MonadLog m) => MonadLog Proxy a' a b' b m r  where
    askLogger = lift askLogger
    localLogger f = lift  . localLogger x
```

This *should* allow you to use `MonadLog` in any of the Pipes types as long as the inner monad is also a `MonadLog`.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not happy about it, either.  What really needs to happen is that Snoyman needs to add an instance (MonadLogger m, MonadTrans t) => MonadLogger (t m) with the code given above.  MonadLogger already depends on Mtl and Proxy is already a MonadTrans, so everything else would be taken care of.  Until that happens, though, they're either going to have to deal with an evil orphan instance or put up with the lifts that they asked the question specifically to avoid.

Comment: Looking again at the MonadLogger code, there does seem to be some MonadTrans options in there, which makes me wonder if there's somehow a better answer?

Comment: The ultra-general instance you described doesn't work. If you look at the instances for the standard transformers, you'll find that they all define `localLogger` somewhat differently. The `ContT` instance is particularly strange, as usual, but the rest are specialized as well.